# Check for banned/inactive

Tags: php, parameters, actionscript-2

So I'm working on a virtual world and I am currently on the part where I am going to try to make the login.php check if the user is banned or not activated. If the user is banned, the banned column will say "1"("0" if not banned.) If the user's account is activated, the active column will say "1"("0" if not activated.) My as2 sends the post paramaters username and pass to login.php. Login.php does this:

```
<?php
$myServer = "localhost";
$myUser = "root";
$myPass = "";
$myDB = "game";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

// The response variable
$res = "res=KO";

// Check incoming data  
if ($_POST['name'] != "" && $_POST['pass'] != "") { 

// Retrieve all rows from the "user_name" and "password" columns from the "account_info" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, password, active, banned FROM users")
or die(mysql_error()); 
}
//create a loop that continues until each row is called
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

//check if client user name/password is the same as the row from database
if ($_POST['name'] == $row['username'] && $_POST['pass'] == $row['password'] && $row['active'] = '1' && $row['banned'] == '0') { //BE AWARE OF "" ''

// If they match, Ok, user found
$res = "res=OK";
break;
}
else if ($_POST['name'] == $row['username'] && $_POST['pass'] == $row['password'] && $row['active'] == '0' && $row['banned'] == '0') 
{
$res = "res=unactive";
}
else if ($_POST['name'] == $row['username'] && $_POST['pass'] == $row['password'] && $row['banned'] == '1' && $row['active'] == '1' )
{
$res = "res=banned";
}

}
print $res;
?>
```

And here's the function that handles the $res:

```
serverIn.onLoad = function(success)
{
    if (success)
    {
        if (this.res == "OK")
        {
            sendLogin()
        }
        else if (this.res == "unactive")
        {
            var win:MovieClip = showWindow("errorWindow")
            win.errorMsg.text = "Your account is not activated."
        }
        else if (this.res == "banned")
        {
            var win:MovieClip = showWindow("errorWindow")
            win.errorMsg.text = "Your account is banned."
        }
        else
        {
            var win:MovieClip = showWindow("errorWindow")
            win.errorMsg.text = "Incorrect username or password"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var win:MovieClip = showWindow("errorWindow")
        win.errorMsg.text = "Connection failed"
    }
}
```

Both files work great, it was working before until I added the part of the login.php that checks if the user is banned. So here's my problem:

I changed my user info in the database so that I'm banned and activated. But the $res being sent to the swf is res=unactive and makes the "User not active" Window come up. When Im banned and active I want the "User banned" popup to come up.

I then changed it so that im NOT banned and I am active. That logs me in fine like it's supposed to.

I then it so that I'm NOT banned and NOT active. That logs in when it's not supposed to. I would expect the "User not activated" window to come up, it doesn't.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you loop through all users instead of making the SQL statement `where username=$user` and `$user` is properly escaped?

Comment: It certainly won't cause you any problems, but "unactive" is ungrammatical. You probably want "inactive" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be significant:

(Line ~29 of the PHP)

```
$row['active'] = '1'
```

This is setting the value to 1, not testing the value against 1.

```
$row['active'] == '1'
```

Also, please don't store user credentials as plaintext!

Comment: It is significant in that it will say every user is active, however, it won't solve the problem. ^^

Comment: His problem is that he is appearing as active when he shouldn't. The 'unactive' state will never occur,  because he first tests for user/pass and then sets the 'unactive' flag to 1. The next test (which should trigger the 'unactive' state) tests user/pass and the 'unactive' flag, which is always set to '1'.

Comment: Thank you. Works great now. When I publish my virtual world I will definitely hash everything.

Comment: @user2228426: Not just plain hashing (that's vulnerable to rainbow tables), but [salting your hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

Comment: Interesting, from "I changed my user info in the database so that I'm banned and activated. But the $res being sent to the swf is res=unactive and makes the "User not active" Window come up. When Im banned and active I want the "User banned" popup to come up. " I didn't think this would solve it as it would show everyone as active. ^^ (ie, I thought it would fix one of the two problems stated. ^^)